# JavaScript full calendar resource timeline two days issue

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In JavaScript full calendar resourcetimeline2days view is showing days excluding the present day and showing the other two days how can I show today?

Comment: We'd like to help, but it's difficult right now because of the lack of usable information in your post. Please edit your question to provide a [mre] of the issue - i.e. enough code etc for us to be able to see the issue if we ran your code. It's unclear what has gone wrong just from the somewhat vague description. See also [ask] - if your question is only one sentence with nothing else in it, then it's almost certainly not useful on Stackoverflow. See also the [tour] for an overview of how Stackoverflow works and how to get the best out of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.